# Using If Statement within SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, case

I have two tables, Table1 and Table 2. Some columns are the same in both. I would like to pull the data depending on whether the column in table2 has an entry or not. I mean, if a data has an entry one of the column in both tables, then I would like to pull data from table2 if not table 1.

Following is the example of the table structure.

TABLE 1 : `Ticket_details`

```
   TIcketID| SubmittedBy|Priority| Ticket_description|current_status
    2010       1000       High      blah...blah        current_assigned
    2020       1000       Normal    gggggggggg         current_assigned
    2030       1100        Low      hhhhhhhhhhhh       current_description
```

TABLE 2: `TICKET_EDIT_DETAILS`

```
    TIcketID| Priority| Ticket_description|
      2020       Low    gggggggggghhhh
```

In this example, the `ticketId` 2020 has an entry in Table2. So I would like to pull `Priority` and `ticket_description`  from Table 2. But TicketIds 2010 and 2030 have no entry in Table 2, so I would like to pull the columns `Priority` and `ticket_description` from Table 1.

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use 'case when'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t1.ticketId, t1.submittedBy,
  COALESCE(t2.priority, t1.priority),
  COALESCE(t2.ticket_description, t1.ticket_description),
  t1.current_status
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ticketId = t2.ticketId
```

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/960dc/1).

Bear in mind that this solution is actually assuming that Priority and TIcket_description are not null on table2. If they were null, then those fields from table1 would be used.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.I think,It gives what you want.

```
SELECT
    td.[TIcketID],
    td.[SubmittedBy],
    (CASE WHEN ted.[Priority] IS NOT NULL THEN ted.[Priority] ELSE td.[Priority] END)AS [priority],
    (CASE WHEN ted.[Ticket_description] IS NOT NULL THEN ted.[Ticket_description] ELSE td.[Ticket_description] END)AS [Ticket_description],
    td.[current_status]
FROM Ticket_details td
LEFT OUTER JOIN TICKET_EDIT_DETAILS ted ON td.[TIcketID]=ted.[TIcketID]
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/dcd4c/4)

Comment: @Raghu, Now SQL Fiddle link is added.